# Relative Importance Weights of USA CPI items

Tags: macroeconomics, inflation, price, price-index

So for example in this release [Table 2. Consumer Price Index for All Urban Consumers (CPI-U): U. S. city average, by detailed expenditure category](https://www.bls.gov/news.release/cpi.t02.htm), the Relative importance weights are stated.

Now I was wondering if there is a possibility to get a time-series of these weights. College Textbooks for example has the item code SSEA011, so the code for a price index of this College Texbooks would be CUUR0000SSEA011. [Series ID Formats](https://www.bls.gov/help/hlpforma.htm#CU)

Is there a way to download the Relative importance weights for the individual items of the CPI, for example for College Textbooks?

Thank you!